# .htacces error 404 codeigniter + bootstrap

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, configuration, url-routing

Why is my link for bootstrap.css link return a wrong one? The link for bootstrap becomes this:

```
http://localhost/ciproj/localhost/ciproj/assets/css/bootstrap.css
```

but I am using a code like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="<?php base_url(); ?>assests/css/bootstrap.css />
```

My config.php is set to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/ciproj';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

My .htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.cs>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|Scripts|css|robots\.txt)
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

and my directory structure is like this

```
-ciproj
   -application
     -system
     -index.php
     -assets
            -css
                -bootstrap.css
            -js
     -.htaccess
```

Comment: have you tried leaving your `base_url` blank.

Comment: @falinsky sorry its not applicable to me. already tried. I know that it has something to do with my .htaccess but I cannot see the problem. As you can see the base_url becomes doubled meaning my rewriterule is not working because i assume i am adding an exeption for css

Comment: im new to SO can you specify how i can clean that .htaccess code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change from

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/ciproj';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ciproj';
```

update:

try

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.cs> 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|Scripts|css|robots\.txt) 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks for clearing it more. now the url for bootstrap.css is correct. But still it is returning a error 404 page not found

Comment: do you have any ideas what i am missing in the directory of config for htaccess?

Comment: nevermind man. its already working. just did a stupid mistake again. Thanks for the help! Cheers!